# Date not parsing the month

Tags: java, android

What are the factors that make a date parsing not parsing the month correctly?

I have this very basic code :

```
    DateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
    Date date = format.parse(dateInterv);
```

`dateInterv` is a `String` with the value "14/06/2016" , and when I parse the date, `date` is in january. Even in debugger I can't see why it transforms 14/06/2016 into 14/01/2016.

Comment: have you tried not using the Locale? `DateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/yyyy"); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your String must be:

```
  DateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.FRENCH);
    Date date = format.parse(dateInterv);
```

because `dd` is for day of month and `DD` is for day of year

Comment: the correct format is `dd/MM/yyyy` actually `mm` is minutes

Comment: wow, it was so dumb from me... Well thanks

Comment: @Vlad....was just a typo error, sorry...

Comment: no, not dumb :) ....you don´t believe how often this happens :)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow any of the following format from [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Date curDate = new Date();

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy zzzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy",
            Locale.ITALIAN);
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
    DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
    System.out.println(DateToStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might wanna change it to this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.French);
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInterv);
    String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```